# Late Answer with legitimate link was deleted (spam false-positive?)

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, spam

I know there is a [new automatic spam detection system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) in Stack Exchange, and am wondering if a Late Answer I was reviewing could have been caught as a false positive.

I was reviewing a Late Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15693196), and checked the link for relevance.  It was a legitimate YouTube video: "Angular 2 - Installing Angular CLI : Tutorial for Beginners"

I went to edit the Answer to add the title of the video, but got

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

I suspect this an over-zealous result of the new spam engine.  Or is something else going on? (Eg, are links to videos not considered appropriate answers?)

There are no other answers to the question, so the Answer, while arguably not great, seems better than nothing.  Worse, it seems the new user is likely legitimately trying to help, and getting shut out.

[Edit] - Knowing of the change in the way spam detection is handled, it may have been a bit of a knee-jerk reaction to think that was the issue, rather considering the possibility that a link-only answer belongs in the "not an answer" category.

Comment: Answers that just contain links and no other explanation (no matter where they link to) are not considered appropriate answers. That could have been a comment.

Comment: By the way, SmokeDetector is a community-run project, not an "official" part of Stack Exchange, and it never caught that post.  Even if it had caught it, it would not have been confident enough to autoflag it.  Even when the system is sure it's spam, it will only cast 3 automatic flags, requiring 3 more users to review and flag it before it's deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Posting a link to a video is not an answer by any means, and that should be deleted regardless of how many other answers there are. Its deletion had nothing to do with spam, and the user actually did receive a comment explaining why their answer was not acceptable (that you wouldn't have been able to see while completing the audit but should be visible now):

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, yes; I can see that now.

Comment: Also, given that the narrator of that video is someone named Piyush, and the answer was posted by someone named Piyush (their third such answer promoting that video), it's pretty clear this was an attempt to promote their company's YouTube channel. I consider that spam.

Comment: @BradLarson A very fair point - I had missed that detail.